# Como mapear uma coluna que não existe no banco?

Tags: java, jpa, annotation

Estou com um pequeno problema ao mapear (JPA) as colunas de uma classe de meu sistema. Tenho alguns procedimentos em banco que fazem muita coisa já e não gostaria de deixar de utilizá-los, mas não sei como mapear.

```
SELECT r.*, ultimo_documento(r.id) as ultimo, ultima_acao(r.id) as ultima,
abcd(r.id, r.nome) as campo_teste
FROM requerimento
```

Tenho na minha classe os campos '`ultimo`, `ultima`, `campo_teste`' mapeados com @Transient.
Mas esses campos não são preenchidos.
Utilizo `@NativeQueries` declaradas antes da entidade.

Como mapear uma coluna que não existe no banco?

Comment: Como assim, amigo? Você precisa ter essas informações persistidas no banco? Se já estão com `@Transient`, não vejo problemas quanto a implementação, a não ser que o compilador acuse algo.

Answer (score 0):

```
query.addScalar("campo_teste", StringType.INSTANCE); // Ou seja lá qual for o tipo
query.list();
```

?